# How to add a line to execute bash script in gulp.js

Tags: javascript, bash, gulp, gulp-watch

I wrote a bash script that will kill the processes running, and I want add the script in my gulp.js file. The file is present in `/webapp/bin/killall.sh`, and could anyone tell me how to add this filepath in gulp.js? I am very new to using gulp, and have no idea how to execute it.

My bash script

```
#!/bin/sh
ps aux | egrep -i 'python manage.py runserver|aptly api serve|python -m SimpleHTTPServer' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```